# PostgreSQL 9.6.1 is extremely slow with PHP 7.1.9 ans Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, postgresql, zend-framework2, php-7.1, postgresql-9.6

I upgraded my PHP version from 5.6 to 7.1.9 and the application (Zend Framework 2) began to work with PostgreSQL DB extremely slow. Simple query took 20-30 seconds or even timeout error. I changed DB to another with version 9.6.2 and now it works excellent. Could you help? I still need my old 9.6.1 DB.

Comment: `explain analyze ...`, https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions .

Comment: How did you measure the speed of the query? Can you elaborate a bit maybe with few example metrics?